# c# modify getter/setter but keep the short form

Tags: c#, setter, getter

I need to do a minor check in C# setter - check if property is an empty string. Right now I ended up with structure like that:

```
        private string property;
        public string Property
        {
           get
           {
              return property;
           }
           set
           {
              if (value.IsNotEmpty())
              {
                   property = value;
              }
           }
        }
```

Instead of

```
public string Property { get; set; }
```

6 lines instead of 1. Is there a way to **insert the logic, but keep it condensed** and elegant?

Answer (score 7):

**No**

Auto-properties (or the "short form") can have access modifiers, but no logic. You are stuck with the code you have.

One thing you *could* do is to encapsulate your `string` in an object that allows for an implicit cast from string (and to string), and checks `IsNotEmpty` before assigning to a underlying value. Also not the most elegant solution, but it would probably allow you to keep the syntactic sugar.

Comment: I came here looking for an answer to just a setter. However, thanks to this I created a struct backed by a string value that had implicit operators that nulled out empty values.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no syntax sugar for such cases (at least up to C# 5.0 - current for 2014).

You can format them differently and use `?:` instead of `if` if it looks nice enough to you:

```
    public string Property
    {
       get { return property; }
       set { property = value.IsNotEmpty() ? value: property;}
    }
```

Comment: +1 I like the ternary operator solution to keep it short and sweet.  `?:` = http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#C.23

Comment: Although... what happens this case if the value of property is empty already and an attempt is made to set it to empty? I suppose you're accessing the backing value so you're ok but careful, if you called `Property` instead of `property` you would end up with an infinite loop.

Comment: @PaulSasik `x = x;` is expected to work correctly for all types (and definitely does for one in framework like `string`). Marginally wasteful to reassign value to itself, but sometime it is more useful to have compact code that easier to read than the fastest code. Indeed you can write infinite recursion but you could do it as well in original code (`Property = value;`) as `get` on the right side of assignment will not cause recursion.

Answer (score 3):

As of C# 7, properties support arrow syntax, making the following possible:

```
private string property;
public string Property
{
    get => property;
    set => property = value.IsNotEmpty() ? value : property;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly what you ask, but perhaps you can use DataAnnotations, for not allowing an empty string. Something like this, in this case a validation exception is raised if the property is null, an empty string (""), or contains only white-space characters.

```
  [Required]
  public string Property { get; set; }
```

Comment: Not a bad idea, but you also need to *answer the question*. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275121/good-answers-but-not-to-the-question-asked?cb=1

Comment: The question is "Is there a way to insert the logic, but keep it condensed and elegant?" I think my answer does it in a different way. No need to down vote it.

Comment: I'm not the down voter, but your answer inserts *different* logic - his doesn't throw an exception on an empty string.

Comment: +1 I like the exception being thrown because the OP as well as the other answers basically allow for silent failure. Consider the client code. You assign a value to an instance of a class but because the value is empty, nothing actually happens. Then you attempt to use the value some lines of code/method calls, later and wham... What went wrong? IMHO there's a fetish on SO for just  *answering the question*. I can't imagine the lunacy that we would unleash upon the world if all we did was *answer the question*. Some of the most useful answers I've seen start more like this one...

Comment: @PaulSasik this answer needs much more context to be ok - as it stands now there is no restrictions on `Property` for general case asked by OP. Adding attribute does nothing by itself - there needs to be code that actually pays attention to attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can always make it like this.

It does compact it but offers no performance boost doing it this way.

```
    private string property;
    public string Property { get { return property; } set { if (value.IsNotEmpty()) property = value; } }
```

Comment: I suppose that is *technically* one line, though its just formatted differently. Not really sure where performance came into this discussion.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Yes but there is no real point in doing it unless you like it more like this. Your answer may be more suitable though. It is a nice option for setting a string and always having a value to it. +1 to your answer.

Comment: Just one reason *not* to do this; it makes debugging the setter nigh on impossible.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Why does it make it impossible ? I've never had a problem and I leave all of my properties like this. Debugging has been rather easy when I do it this way.

Comment: How do you set a breakpoint inside the setter? There is no line to break on, at least when I try it.

Comment: It lets me set the breakpoints fine. Are you making sure to click inside the setter and not outside of it ? Also what version of visual studio do you use ? I use 2013.

Comment: I'm in VS 2012, but I'm clicking in the bar to the left (which contains the entire line, including the getter *and* setter). I can't break in just the setter. In fact, it breaks in the getter for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63567/discussion-between-deathismyfriend-and-bradleydotnet).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [answer from @BradleyDotNET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26539527/1109858) I created the following struct to hold NonEmptyStrings, basically if set empty it reverts to null.

```cs
[JsonConverter(typeof(NonEmptyStringSystemTextJsonConverter))]
public readonly struct NonEmptyString
{
    [AdaptMember] //Mapster attribute to allow for cloning
    private readonly string? _value;

    
    public NonEmptyString(string? value) => _value = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ? null : value;

    public static implicit operator NonEmptyString(string? value)
    {
        return new NonEmptyString(value);
    }

    public static implicit operator string?(NonEmptyString value)
    {
        return value._value;
    }

    public override string ToString() => _value!;
    private class NonEmptyStringSystemTextJsonConverter : JsonConverter<NonEmptyString>
    {
        public override NonEmptyString Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) => new(reader.GetString());

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, NonEmptyString value, JsonSerializerOptions options) => writer.WriteStringValue(value._value);
    }
}
```